# Hosting site on http and https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to host my ASP.NET MVC website with both http and https bindings.
But only few paths should be available via http, where as all paths should be available via https.

e.g.
My application exposes following urls:

```
https://server/v1/setup
https://server/v1/exchange
https://server/v1/time
```

I want time url to be available via http as well

```
http://server/v1/time
```

I do not want to set any rules in IIS. Is there any way I can control urls available via http in code?

I also had loook at RequiresHttps attribute, but there is some redirection issue with it.
If http request is made for not allowed paths, response should be 404 (not found).

Comment: If the HTTP site and HTTPS sites interact in any way I would suggest for security concerns to only do HTTPS.  You won't have that much of a slow down if that is your concern but the potential attack vector of HTTP mixed with HTTPS is not something you want.  Check out Troy Hunt's blog.  Here's a couple blogs that might help illustrate my thought on this.  http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/06/understanding-risk-of-mixed-content.html  & http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html

Answer (score 3):

You could make an an actionfilter to check for https.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class HttpsOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the MVC framework before the action method executes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Just place the attribute on top of the controllers you want to be https only

```
[HttpsOnly]
public class SecureController : Controller
{
     // your actions here
}
```

You can even target just actions

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [HttpsOnly]
    public ActionResult SecureAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [RequireHttpsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.requirehttpsattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) can still be used in this case.

Decorating your Controllers of Actions with this will Redirect GET requests to the Secure version, and throw errors for all other methods.

If you extend from this method, you can override the handling to either always return a 404, or to use the default handling.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RequireHttpsExtendedAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public RequireHttpsExtendedAttribute(bool throwNotFound = false)
    {
        ThrowNotFound = throwNotFound;
    }

    private bool ThrowNotFound { get; set; }

    protected override void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (ThrowNotFound)
            throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

        base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses!! I came up with solution of using custom route constraints.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Test1_default",
            "Test1/CurrentTime",
            new { action = "CurrentTime", controller = "Default1" },
            new { https = new HttpsConstraint() });
    }
}

public class HttpsConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection;
    }
}
```